# "something includes reference to someone"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> In questions with *shall we?* *shall* generally includes **reference** to the listener (= ‘you and I / we’). *Shall we?* is therefore used in suggestions about shared behaviour. This accounts for the use of *shall we?* as a tag question (in BrE) after imperatives beginning *Let’s...*: *Let’s have an ice-cream, shall we?* (In AmE *shall we?* is sometimes heard as a complete utterance equivalent to *Shall we go?*)

(from <Meaning and the English Verb 3rd Ed.> by Geoffrey Leech)

Here, What's the meaning(or dictionary definition) of the word "reference"?

Comment: Which dictionaries did you use?  The first defn in Cambridge would seem to fit "mention of something".    The listener is mentioned (by the use of the word "we")

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry but, now I think here, "include reference to"="have reference to"="relate to". That is, I think here, the word "reference" should be considered with the former verb "include", rather than being considered independently. How do you think about my opinion?

Comment: In fact, Leech distinguishes *shall we* (here, *we* means the speakers and doesn't include the listener) from another *shall we* (here, *we* includes the listener) in <Meaning and the English Verb 1st Ed.> and says like this, "(the latter) *we* includes refernce to the listner (=you and I / we)." But, he says like the following in <Meaning and the English Verb 2nd and 3rd Eds.>, "In questions with *shall we?* *shall* generally includes reference to the listener (= ‘you and I / we’)."

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to overthink this.  "A reference" is a mention of something.

In the short idiom "Shall we?"  the speaker uses the word "we", and so implicitly mentions the listener.  In this context "we" is understood to mean "you and I" and not "they and I". Thus the tag question "...shall we?" contains an implicit reference to the listener.  The listener is included in the reference, along with the speaker.

The author is noting that "I'll get an ice cream, shall I?" would be a very odd utterance, but "Let's get an ice cream, shall we?" is normal.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful reply.